# Relu derivative value

Tags: backpropagation, activation-function

[image]

I have a stupid question on the derivative of relu activation function. After the finding the difference of the true output $t_k$ and predicted output $a_k$, why is the value of the $d_{a3}$ \ $d_{z3}$ is 1. Although the derivative seemed to be defined differently. Whenever x greater one then 1 otherwise 0. My answer would have been 0 and not 1 as it is done in the picture below.